# Creating a symbolic link to Sublime Text2

Tags: path, sublimetext2

I am installing software on my MacBook Pro in preparation for a Rails tutorial. One of the steps involves creating a symbolic link to Sublime Text 2 so that it can be used in Bash. To do this, Sublime Text advises

> The first task is to make a symlink to `subl`. Assuming you've placed Sublime Text 2 in the Applications folder, and that you have a `~/bin` directory in your path, you can run:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

When I run this command, I get

```
ln: /Users/nngrey/bin/subl: No such file or directory
```

My path seems to include ~/bin:

```
echo $PATH

/Users/nngrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin:/Users/nngrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/Users/nngrey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/Users/nngrey/.rvm/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$PATH` does not, in fact, contain `~/bin`. If you look closely, `/Users/nngrey/bin` is not there. The original `ln -s ...` command probably failed because `~/bin` doesn't exist. To make it, run `mkdir ~/bin` from Terminal. Then, rerun the `ln` command. Finally, run `~/bin/subl ~/.profile` to open your `~/.profile` file in Sublime, and add the following line to the bottom:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

Save the file, then restart your Terminal session and you should be able to type `subl filename` from the command line in any directory.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to make some progress. However, when I tried to run ~/bin/subl ~/.profile, Sublime Text opened a blank file. Since you said, to add the line to the bottom, I assume this is not correct? I added export PATH=$PATH:~/bin anyway and restarted terminal but the subl command did not work. Did I miss something?

Comment: run `ls -a .*` in your home directory and look for a file named either `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` (I assume you're using `bash` and not another shell like `zsh` or `tcsh`). If you find one of those files, then put the `export ...` command in it. If you find both, put it in both. One of them will work!

Comment: Excellent! That worked. I still don't understand why ~/bin is /Users/nngrey/bin as opposed to /bin: or usr/bin: I thought ~ meant "stuff that comes before" but maybe it describes a specific path? I guess I need to study this more. Anyway, I am glad it works! Thanks for your help. Nathan

Comment: @Nathan - `~` in Unix refers specifically to the user's home directory. For an overview of the shell, check out Apple's [Command-Line Primer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/CommandLInePrimer/CommandLine.html) and learn to use the [`man` pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/manpages.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/manpages). And, in this situation, as in many others, Google is definitely your friend. Finally, if you have specific questions, check out http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please click the check mark to accept it. It will mark the question as resolved, and we'll both get reputation points.